# SharePoint list that connects and pull related information in multiple lists and libraries

Tags: list, lookup-column

I have a SharePoint list that has a unique column which is looked up in five other lists with related details pertaining to the items mentioned in the unique column

I need to have a page with this SharePoint list that the column originates. and every time someone clicks on any row item on the list. the row item should open up in a new page with other lists and libraries that have valid data related to that row item.

Can someone help me? I'm not a developer but understand HTML coding but a SharePoint Administrator and practically change the look and feel of the site and its functionality

Answer (score 0):

`Option 1:`If you are trying to avoid custom code, the only way I see if to create connected web parts. So you will have a page with the master list view web part (the one with the unique id) and underneath it place all the other lists (list view web parts) and you create a connection between them based on the unique ID.

`Option 2:` this is a little heavy on coding (dont recommend it cuz it will take time to code it but it can do exactly what you are asking for)

Create a calculated column on that list to store a link to the page you will be creating later. The calculated column will concatenate the link with id (something like `="http://xyz/pages/mypage.aspx?id="&[ID"]`)

now you will create that page (i.e. mypage.aspx) and inject a script in the page using content editor or script editor depending on SP version you are using.

Since I dont know the exact name of your lists and what exacly you want to show, I will just refer you to a page which can help you understand how to retrive items from list and libraries (but keep in mind that the first to do is to get the id from the URL to use inside the code)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx